# Does Ron ever introduce himself as "Ronald Weasley" in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, names

Per [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/ron-weasley-infographic) (*formerly Pottermore*), Ron's full name is **Ronald Bilius Weasley** and he uses his family name Ron Weasley. I recognize that even the first time he met Harry, he called himself "Ron" and not "Ronald":

> Ron: Excuse me, do you mind? Everywhere else is full.
>
> Harry: No, not at all.
>
> Ron: {sits across from Harry} I'm Ron, by the way. Ron Weasley.

I only remember when Ron gets a Howler in *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, we find out that his real name was Ronald.

Did Ron ever mention his full name anywhere?

Comment: Has anyone in the world actually been named "Ron"? I'm pretty sure it's always a shortened version of "Ronald".

Comment: @LevenTrek - In the UK, there are approximately 10 "Ron"s born each year; http://names.darkgreener.com/#ron

Comment: @LevenTrek “Ron” is also a nickname for someone whose full name is Aaron or Cameron.

Comment: Sounds to me like you may be from a country/culture where using shortened nicknames is not as normal as in English speaking countries (at least US and UK), so I'll add: As far as I understand, going by Ron in all but the most formal of settings, when your real name is Ronald, is not unusual in those countries.

Comment: @Kazim yes usually in my family, we speak forrmal and only family name when close friend only. I dont think cut off someone 's name is normal in other culture

Comment: @someoneuseless Your assumption is bad: in many parts of the world, using nicknames is extremely common. Using someone's full name when they have introduced themselves with a nickname can be off-putting. But if you want to pursue that, it's likely best to ask another question (maybe at the interpersonal stack?)

Comment: @Valorum I wonder how many parents named their kids "Ron" *before* the HP saga was written...

Comment: @someoneuseless out of curiosity, what drove the question? Why do you care? (I've no objection to you caring! Just a weird curiosity about what got you to the point of wanting to know the answer! :D )

Comment: "I dont think cut off someone 's name is normal in other culture" You thought wrong. It is very common, in English anyway. Also, _everyone_ called Ron is actually named Ronald (OK, I'm sure there are rare exceptions, but that's the rule). We already knew his name was Ronald before the book said it, because that's how English works. Ron is short for Ronald. It's not informal, either.

Comment: @Brondahl well I read some fanfic and realize Ron name isn't Ron and then I search google and fount it real name. So bizarre because I only call that for best friend, lover or in family. English isn't my mother language so I dont know about that.

Comment: @someoneuseless ah, that makes perfect sense. :) As has been explained by user91988, name contraction is extremely common in English-speaking cultures. For many names it is actively the norm, and in a few cases the "original" long form of the name is considered extremely antiquated.

Comment: Where a short form is used as the default ("Tom" rather than "Thomas", say), then there is a cultural norm that using the full form is an indication of seriousness or formality. Often it's a parent indicating to a child that they're in extreme trouble (like Molly does with the Howler), or a formal rite or ritual (the sorting, and the will), or when Dumbledore says it in front of the mirror - indicating a gravitas to the event.

Comment: Side note, I've known people with legal first names of Bill, Billy, Bob, Bobby, Jim, Jimmy, and Ken (no Kenny yet). They are not necessarily short forms of longer names like William, Robert, James or Kenneth.

Comment: "Harry" is also traditionally a nickname for names such as "Henry" or  "Harold".  "Prince Harry" is actually named Henry.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Textually, we learn that Ron is short for Ronald in the middle of the first book, when Dumbledore and Harry speak about the Mirror of Erised.

> ‘Yes and no,’ said Dumbledore quietly. ‘It shows us nothing more or less than the deepest, most desperate desire of our hearts. You, who have never known your family, see them standing around you. **Ronald Weasley,** who has always been overshadowed by his brothers, sees himself standing alone, the best of all of them.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/72193.Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher_s_Stone?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=cKlkjl6QQu&rank=1)</sup></sub>

And it's not until book 7 that we learn his full name.

> ‘“The Last Will and Testament of Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore” … yes, here we are … “to Ronald Bilius Weasley, I leave my Deluminator, in the hope that he will remember me when he uses it.”’
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/136251.Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows)</sup></sub>

At no point does he ever *introduce* himself as Ronald, although his teachers and parents use the name repeatedly.

Comment: this answer is better than mine but I'm pretty sure McGonagall says "Ronald" for the sorting hat... (movie/book 1)

Comment: @LevenTrek - In the book it's told from Harry's persective; "*then it was Ron’s turn. He was pale green by now. Harry crossed his fingers under the table and a second later the hat had shouted, ‘GRYFFINDOR!’* - No mention of his name

Comment: Spoiler alert? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry For Harry Potter? It's 2020.

Comment: @user91988 Well, I've never seen it

Answer (score 20):

The first time the name "Ronald" is spoken is in the first movie, when Professor McGonagall calls him up to be sorted into his house.

According to the movie scripts, he never *introduces* or *refers to himself* as Ronald.

Comment: I just noticed that the ordering of the students in the movie version of Sorting is all over the place.

Comment: @HighVoltage what, were you not ordered by narrative tension at your school?

Answer (score 3):

Ron presents his name as Ronald on the sign fixed to his bedroom door. This is first seen when Harry arrives at the Burrow in Chapter 3 of Chamber of Secrets:

> They climbed two more flights until they reached a door with peeling paint and a small plaque on it, saying 'Ronald's Room'.

It's not his full name (there's no mention of "Bilius"), and it's not verbal, but Ron is definitely introducing himself to his guests as "Ronald" here.

Comment: It's unlikely that he made the sign himself. Probably it was crafted or bought by his parents.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the sort of thing he is forced to keep there, considering how much agency he has in decorating the rest of his room. If he chooses to keep it there, it doesn't matter who created or gave him the plaque.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad answer, just that door signs are normally bought by the parents rather than by the child, and we know that Mrs Weasley uses his full name.